# Python problem with A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python

I am working on a python project, and when I try to create a new variable in the DataFrame. I get 'A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead' Here is my code:df_total['Final Average']=(((df_total['Test1'] + df_total['Test2'])/2*0.4)+((df_total['Hw1']+df_total['Hw2']+df_total['Hw3']+df_total['Hw4']+df_total['Hw5'])/5*0.5)+(df_total['Project']*0.1))[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JwSM.jpg)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Best answer is to really documentate yourself on this subject that is the pain in the ass of all pandas beginner.

Generally it is because you just forgot to make a copy of a dataset.

I guess you declared somewhere :

```py
df_total = df_other[...]
```

It should have been

```py
df_total = df_other[...].copy()
```

https://realpython.com/pandas-settingwithcopywarning/